Convergence of independent variables / martingales
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $X_n \geq 0$ and $E(X_n) = 1$.
Assume that the almost sure limit
$Z = \prod_{i=1}^{inf} X_i$
exists. Set $Y_n = \sqrt{X_n}$ and $Z_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. Show that:

$E(Y_n) \leq 1$,
The sequence $\sqrt{Z_n} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ is uniformly integrable,
If $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} E(Y_n) = 0$, then $Z = 0$ almost surely.

Continuation:
Now assume that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} E(Y_n) > 0$. Show that $E(Z) = 1$. (Hint: Set $W_n = \prod_{i=n}^{\infty} X_i$. What can be said about $E(\sqrt{W_n})$ and $E(W_n)$ for large $n$?)
————
I had no problem solving the first part. Utilizing Jensens Inequality and Fatous Theorem made it quite easy. However I am stuck on the continuation. I tried working with the hint and tried solving for the square root, however I can only get an inequality of $E(W_n)$<=1. I am also unable to use martingales since we haven’t covered that part in the lecture yet - I think it could work using them.

I added solutions for 1-3 just for completeness.

By Jensen inequality
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_{n}) = \mathbb{E}\left( \sqrt{ X_{n} }\right) \le \sqrt{ \mathbb{E} X_{n} } = 1. 
$$
Any sequence of random variables $\{U\}$ such that for some $\delta>0, C>0$
$$
\sup \left\{ \mathbb{E} \lvert U_{n} \rvert ^{1+\delta} \right\} < C 
$$
is uniformly integrable. Here $\mathbb{E}\left(\sqrt{ Z_{n} }^{2}\right) = \mathbb{E}Z_{n}=1$.
By Fatou's lemma
$$
0 = \lim \inf\limits_{n \to \infty} \prod \limits_{k=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}(Y_{n})= \lim\inf\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(Z_{n}) \ge \mathbb{E}\lim \inf\limits_{n \to \infty} Z_{n} = \mathbb{E}Z.
$$
Then $\mathbb{E}Z = 0$, and $Z=0$ a.s. because $Z \ge 0$.
Using uniform integrability of $\sqrt{ Z_{n} }$ we apply Vitali convergence theorem - Wikipedia and get that
$$
\sqrt{ Z_{n} } \stackrel{L_{1}}{\to } \sqrt{Z},
$$
the same is true for
$$
\prod_{i=k}^{n} Y_{k} \stackrel{L_{1}}{\to } \sqrt{ W_{k} }.
$$
Which means that
$$
\prod_{i=k}^{n} \mathbb{E}{Y_{k}} \stackrel{L_{1}}{\to } \mathbb{E}{\sqrt{ W_{n} }}.
$$
Given, that $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}{Y_{k}} > 0$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N > 0$, that for $n > N$ we have
$$
\sqrt{ \mathbb{E} W_{n} } \ge \mathbb{E}\sqrt{ W_{n} } > 1 -\varepsilon.
$$
And the proof is finished with $\varepsilon \to 0$ in
$$
\mathbb{E}Z = \mathbb{E}Z_{n-1} \cdot\mathbb{E}W_{n} = \mathbb{E}W_{n} > 1 - \varepsilon.
$$

P.S. 
$Z_{n}$ is a martingale and by the Doob's $L_{1}$ convergence theorem $\mathbb{E}Z = 1$ is equivalent to
$$
Z_{n} \stackrel{L_{1}}{\to } Z.
$$

That’s a really great answer - I probably would have never figured that out!
